# Teechart pro v 3.0 (issues)

Tags: windows-7, vb6, teechart

Sorry if i'm asking this on the wrong forum...

Hello. We use Teechart pro v.3.0 (yeah...it's old) in one of our projects here...We upgraded our pc's and so the SO in the process...we use Win 7 enterprise 32bits now.

We've installed this component in our pcs and it works fine..but not on my pc. My installation process won't complete. It gets stuck on "updating system configuration". When i check its installation folder, it seems to be ok...here's what i've tried so far:

```
1) Registered its .OCX files
2) Put the OCX files in the system and system32 folders (there's a .txt file that asks you to do so)
```

None of the above worked for me. And here's more...i can't uninstall it. It should have a Installation.log file inside its folder but there isn't one, since my installation process didn't finish...

I've got the .ocx files from my co-workers pcs but no success..i thought that uninstalling it and installing it again could work..how can i uninstall it without having to format my pc?

Answer (score 1):

You can install/uninstall using *regsvr32* command as I explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3385&p=12340&hilit=regsvr32#p12340). For example, to register an .ocx control use:

*regsvr32 InstallPath\TeeChart7.ocx*

To unregister:

*regsvr32 -u InstallPath\TeeChart7.ocx*